# perl configuration files reading

Tags: perl, config

Hi i am doing the perl configuration files using `Config::Simple`
And my configuration file is

```
[Dialer External]
pass=pass2
user=user2

[Dialer Onboard]
pass=pass1
user=user1
```

Now my actual requirement is that i have to read the comment lines also.
If i have file like this

```
[Dialer External]
pass=pass2
user=user2

[Dialer Onboard]
pass=pass1
;user=user1
```

I will be able to read the line `;user=user1` also.I know it is not fair to read the comments.
But is there any way to read  and write the data in comment line.With the help of  `Config::Simple` i guess it is not possible to do this.

Is there any way to do like this in perl. 
please suggest and correct me in this regard. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you want to do with them?  Can you open the file and search for lines that start with a ';'?

Comment: this configuration file will be used by two programs, so that with comment parameter will be read by one application and remaining by others application.

Comment: If you controll both consumers of the file and the file itself, you simply use a different format to mark ("comment") the settings you only want one of them to read, and implement that in both consumers accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try removing [the semicolon on this line](https://metacpan.org/source/SHERZODR/Config-Simple-4.59/Simple.pm#L221) of the source code. But you would also need to then remove semicolons from the start of option names.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse this is possible - but rather not with the module Config::Simple as it is *now*. I just read in the [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~sherzodr/Config-Simple-4.59/Simple.pm) that *'Retaining comments while writing the configuration files back and/or methods for manipulating comments. Everyone loves comments!'* is a **TODO** of this module right now.

have you digged in the source? it should be rather simple to manipulate the read() in such a way that ;-prefixed lines are not ignored, but aswell pushed into the hash.

Comment: i have tried to find in the source...but that has not helped

Comment: well then i would suggest you write the parser yourself:

`while(<>) {
         if($_ ~= /;/) {
                  #push it onto some datastructure
         }
}`